# Construct object-phrases in korean

Tags: grammar

I was trying to construct a sentence like the following.

> 1. Would you show me where I can throw this away?

I am not a grammar expert but if I have to translate just

> 2. Would you show me this

I would translate as

> 너가 이거를 보여 주세요

Now, to me, the difference between 1. and 2. is that instead of having an object (*This = 이것*) made up of a single noun I have a whole phrase (*where I can throw this away*)

So I have an *object phrase*. I don't think, to my knowledge at least, there's a unique way to formulate object phrases in korean, in this context I would use the indirect quotation marker *다고*. Therefore I would translate my sentence as follows

> 넌 내가 어디에 이거를 버릴 수 있다고 보여 주세요

I don't know if it sounds natural, however I more wonder if in this context the use of 다고 to construct "object phrase". As I don't know if there's a pattern I wonder if there's some construction in korean grammar for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Would you show me where I can throw this away?
>    이것을 어디에 버릴 수 있는지 알려주시겠어요?
> 2. Would you show me this
>    이것 좀 알려주시겠어요?

1️⃣ show's meaning : LET SEE 보여 주세요 → TEACH 알려주세요

2️⃣ 이것 (*= where I can throw this away* & You can omit particles "을")
이거/이거를 : informal&casual, 이것/이것을 : Normally used

3️⃣ "-다고"
In this case it's not good.
I think useing '-다고', when you want to convey or report something.
For example, "현아한테 이거 버린**다고** 말해줄래?"(*Would you tell Hyunah that I'm going to throw this away?*)

Actually, I don't know much about grammar("object phrase"), but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> 넌 내가 어디에 이거를 버릴 수 있다고 보여 주세요.

This sentence is incorrect.

First, you don't include the subject in an imperative sentence (also true in English).

Second, Korean has VERB + -지 which makes a question-based noun phrase of clause out of a verb.  You always use this ending to create a clause containing "if", "whether", or any of the "wh" clauses in English.  Depending on the verb tense, -지 may be -는지 (present), -(아/어)ㅆ는지 (past) or -(으)ㄹ지 (future).

Exampels:

- Do you know where 영수 was / is / will be? = 영수가 어디 있었는지 / 있는지 / 있을지 알아?
- How did / do / will you go to Busan? = 부산에 어떻게 갔어 / 가 / 갈 거야?

So your sentence can be phrased as:

- 제가 이거를 어디에 버릴 수 있는지 보여 주세요 / 알려 주세요 = Please show / tell me where I can throw this away.
- 제가 이걸 어디에 버릴 수 있는지 알려 주시겠어요? = Would you please tell me where I can throw this away?
- 제가 이걸 어디에 버려야 되는지 알려 주시겠어요? = Would you please tell me where I *should* throw this away?

In practice, however, we're more likely to say this simplified version.

- 이거 어디에 버리는 건지 아세요? = Do you know where we're supposed to throw this away?

VERB + -는 것인지/건지 expresses a general rule or practice here, so it works well in this kind of sentences.

Comment: To my knowledge, the -지 is an *indirect quotation marker*, hence it should only be used when making questions. If I want to say "I think the weather is good today" I would write "오늘 날씨가 좋아다고 생각해요" I don't think I can write "오늘 날씨가 좋안지 생각해요" as I think it would be implicitly phrased as a question. (My comment is based on what I studied, feel free to point out mistakes). Regardless anyway in my two attempts in this comment there's a noun phrase in both, but it serves different purposes based on the marker.

Comment: "I think the weather is good today" has no element of question, so it is simply 오늘 날씨가 좋다고 생각해요.  If you make it yes/no question, you don't need -지 (one thing I forgot to say in my post), but for any other question, like if/whether it is good, how good, etc. you need -지.  오늘 날씨가 좋을지 안 좋을지 알아요? (Do you know whether it will be a fine day or not today?). When a question phrase involving if, whether, how, why, what, when, or where is encapsulated (i.e. a compound sentence), you needs the -지 ending of the verb.

Comment: But therefore, there's no unique way to construct noun phrases in Korean or to label phrases as such, because it depends on the context (in this case question vs no question).

Comment: There is no one way for all cases, there is typically only one way for each type of embedded questions. 
Embedded questions require -지. -라고/-다고 is used when you ask about someone's thought or opinion, as in 그 사람 말이 옳다고 생각하세요? (Do you think what he said is right?).  But note that in this case the embedded clause (그 사람 말이 옳다) is a statement and not a question.  If the embedded part is a question, you need -지 to formulate it.

Comment: Also, I said the wrong thing in my earlier comment that you can formulate yes/no question without -지.  You still need -지 to embed it, as in 회사가 잘되고 있는지 말해 주세요 = Tell me if the company is doing well.  There is another way to phrase it though, like 회사가 잘되고 있는 게/것이 맞아요?, but this -게 맞아요 has a more colloquial feel and can't be used to ask what, how, why and the like.

Comment: Do you have some reference for your last comment? (like a grammar book or something).

Comment: Here's one with a lot of examples of the -지 forms  (https://explorekorean.net/intermediate1-lesson1/).  You can search on "embedded questions in Korean".  If you wanted to check -게/것이 맞아요, you can search on "게 맞아요" with double quotes around it to see example usages.  It is not the most standard phrasing (although common in everyday speech), so many grammar books may not have a section on it.